# How do I handle malicious file names in this situation

Tags: bash, directory

"$BIN"'/temp-get'

```
#!/bin/bash

OPTIONS=''

function help {
  {
  echo 'temp-get $NAME?'
  echo ' -> get the temp directories with the prefix'
  echo '( if multiple directories with prefix exist       '
  echo '  they will be returned in reverse chronological  ' 
  echo '  order                                          )'
  } >&2
}

OPTIONS=''

__DIRNAME=$(
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ];do
__DIRNAME="$(builtin cd -P "$(dirname "$SOURCE")" && pwd)"
SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
[[ "$SOURCE" != /* ]] && SOURCE="$__DIRNAME/$SOURCE"
done
echo "$( builtin cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE")" && pwd )"
)
source "$__DIRNAME"'/_config_'

OPTERR=1

(( ${#flags} )) && {
  while getopts $OPTIONS opt ${flags[@]}; do
    case $opt in
       -)
            case "${OPTARG}" in
              *)
              echo 'Invalid long option: -'"$opt$OPTARG" >&2
              help
              exit 1
              ;;
            esac
        ;;
       h)
        help
        exit 1
        ;;
      \?)
        echo 'Invalid option: '"$OPTARG" >&2
        help
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
  done
}

OPTIND=0;unset OPTARG

set -o pipefail


[ -n "${1-}" ] && {
  echo "$PATH_TO_TEMP"'/'*'-'"$1" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -r
} || {
  echo "$PATH_TO_TEMP"'/'* | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -r
}

exit $?
```

dangerous cmd

```
list=( "`"$BIN"'/temp-get' "${1-}"`" )

for dir in ${list[@]} ; do 
  echo $dir
  echo --
done;
```

malicious folder

```
mkdir "`echo -e 'got\nyou'`"
```

I am especially uncertain where to handle this in the parsing of the output of temp-get or in the dangerous command . Ideally I would like to treat this bad file name as if nothing was wrong with it ( which technically nothing is ) .

Comment: http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html

Comment: http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html

Comment: Show us your `temp-get` script and we might be able to tell you what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: The *best* way to do this is generally to use a different programming language - [handling arbitrary filenames in Bash](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh) is unfortunately way too complicated.

In your specific case the *only* place you can handle this is in `temp-get` - it *must* output a NUL-separated list of filenames to be able to handle arbitrary file names in the parent script. Any other separator can be part of a path. Then the parent script can loop over that output not by putting it in an array but by passing it to `while IFS= read -r -d''`.

Comment: I swear to raptor jesus if this works out bash will be the first thing i fix ; its so hopelessly perfect and so sadly every one who remembers what it did is long gone .

Comment: What do you mean? Or are you just ranting?

Comment: Programming languages, tools and techniques are getting *better*, not worse, with time. *Good* programmers weren't more intelligent before, they did what they could with the tools at their disposal. Better tools means it's easier for *everyone* to get into programming, meaning that the *average* programmer today is probably less intelligent than before, but they are solving problems of a complexity the programmers of previous decades could only dream of. Having used more than a dozen languages I can honestly say Bash is in the bottom five for building complex systems.